# How to get a min of the selected count in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the min from a good selection of count.

```
SELECT selectSumOfToyCount.kidsFname, MIN(selectSumOfToyCount.sumToyCount)
(SELECT kidFName,  SUM(kids_to_toys.toyCount) sumToyCount
    FROM kids
        NATURAL JOIN kids_to_toys
        NATURAL JOIN toys
    GROUP BY kidFName
) selectSumOfToyCount
GROUP BY selectSumOfToyCount.kidsFname
```

The select statement inside `()` works but it keeps giving me an error from the outside statement.
I am assuming I have the alias correct?

`selectSumOfToyCount` for the inside `()` selected statement,
`sumToyCount` for the sum.

Comment: I haven't evaluated your query, I just noticed that 'SELECT selectSumOfToyCount.kidsFname' has an 's' in kidsFname where the inner select does not have an s in that name.   Ditto for the Group by clause.  Remove the extra 's' letters and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You're missing a FROM (in the outer clause)

I've purposely changed a few names to point out a few things.

```
    SELECT selectSumOfToyCountAlias.kidsFname, MIN(selectSumOfToyCountAlias.MyAliasSumToyCount)
FROM
    (SELECT kidFName,  SUM(kids_to_toys.toyCount) MyAliasSumToyCount
        FROM kids
            NATURAL JOIN kids_to_toys
            NATURAL JOIN toys
        GROUP BY kidFName
    ) selectSumOfToyCountAlias
    GROUP BY selectSumOfToyCountAlias.kidsFname
```

Comment: I edited my answer.  You're missing a FROM clause on the outer SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Just order by desc and fetch the top row.

```
select * from (
 SELECT kidFName,  SUM(kids_to_toys.toyCount) sumToyCount
 FROM kids
    NATURAL JOIN kids_to_toys
    NATURAL JOIN toys
GROUP BY kidFName
)  order by sumToyCount desc limit 0,1
```